# ngModel, update value in child component with cancel option

Tags: angular, components, angular-ngmodel

I have this table at **parent component**:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of arrUsers">
     <td>
         <app-popupuser [user]=user id="{{user._id}}"></app-popupuser>
         {{user.name}}
     </td>
     <td>
          <span (click)=open_user(user._id)>Open User</span>
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

In **child component** popupuser I have this:

```
<div class="bold-word">Name: </div>
<span class="show-original">{{user.name}}</span>
<span class="edit-value">
    <input [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" type="text">
</span>
```

When I update the value, everything is ok, the name is upadated on the db **and** on the front-end of both parent and child component.
My problem is that i cannot find a way to cancel the update.

For example if i change the **value of the name in the input**, because of the ngModel the value will change on the **front end of the parent component**.

How can i **cancel the changes of the popupuser** so when i close the popup the **name at the front end of parent component** will go back to the original value.

I guess that there are ways to do that but I would like a solution (of course if possible) where i could get back the whole user, and not have to deal with each field of the user object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child component, in ngOnInit use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the inserted user and bind it to your child component template. This way, the original user won't have any affect.

Something like this:

```
@Input() user: User;
innerUser: User;

ngOnInit() {
   this.innerUser = new User();
   Object.assign(this.innerUser, user);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you my savior, been struggling for like 3 hours or something xD